# List with output from for loop returns empty

Tags: r, for-loop, crosstab, r-raster

I have written a code to obtain crosstab results of a rasterstack for different regions (delimited by a shapefile) covering the raster. However, I am getting an empty list.

This is the function:

```
transitions <- function(bound, themat) {    # bound = shapefile # themat = rasterstack
    result = vector("list", nrow(bound))    # empty result list
    names(result) = bound@data$GEOCODIGO

    for (i in 1:nrow(bound)) {    # this is the number of polygons to iterate through
        single <- bound[i,]    # selects a single polygon
        clip <- mask(crop(themat, single), single)    # crops the raster to the polygon boundary

        result[i] <- crosstab(clip, digits = 0, long = FALSE, useNA = FALSE)
        return(result)
    }
}
```

I have tested the steps for the first object in the shapefile/bound outside of the for loop; and it worked well. But I still cannot figure out why I am getting an empty list. Any ideas?

Comment: Put `return(result)` outside the `for` loop. And I would use `result[[i]] <- crosstab(...)` with double `[[` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data:

```
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
b <- brick(raster(p), nl=2)
values(b) = sample(2, 200, replace=TRUE)
```

fixed function:

```
transitions <- function(poly, rast) {    
    result = vector("list", nrow(poly))
    for (i in 1:nrow(poly)) {  
        clip <- mask(crop(rast, poly[i,]), poly[i,])   
        result[[i]] <- crosstab(clip, digits = 0, long = FALSE, useNA = FALSE)
    }
    return(result)
}

transitions(p, b)
```

An alternative would be to use extract

```
e <- extract(b, p)
```

To tabulate as in crosstab:

```
ee <- lapply(e, function(x) aggregate(data.frame(count=rep(1, nrow(x))), data.frame(x), FUN=sum))
```

To understand that last line, you need to unpack it.

```
class(e)
#[1] "list"
length(e)
#[1] 12
e[[1]]
#     layer.1 layer.2
#[1,]       1       1
#[2,]       1       2
#[3,]       2       2
#[4,]       2       1
#[5,]       2       1
#[6,]       1       2
#[7,]       2       2
```

`e` is a list with the same length as the number of polygons (see `length(p)`)

Let's that the first element and aggregate it to get a table with cases and counts.

```
x <- e[[1]]

aggregate(data.frame(count=rep(1, nrow(x))), data.frame(x), FUN=sum)
#  layer.1 layer.2 count
#1       1       1     1
#2       2       1     2
#3       1       2     2
#4       2       2     2
```

A similar approach via table (the difference is that you could get Freq values that are zero

```
as.data.frame(table(x[,1], x[,2]))
#  Var1 Var2 Freq
#1    1    1    1
#2    2    1    2
#3    1    2    2
#4    2    2    2
```

Now wrap the function you like into a `lapply`

```
z <- lapply(e, function(x) aggregate(data.frame(count=rep(1, nrow(x))), data.frame(x), FUN=sum))
```

And to take it further, bind the data.frames and add an identifier to link the data back to the polygons

```
y <- do.call(rbind, z,)
y$id <- rep(1:length(z), sapply(z, nrow))

head(y)
#  Var1 Var2 Freq id
#1    1    1    1  1
#2    2    1    2  1
#3    1    2    2  1
#4    2    2    2  1
#5    1    1    1  2
#6    2    1    2  2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It worked pretty well now. Still, I did not follow what the last line `lapply(e, function(x) aggregate(data.frame(count=rep(1, nrow(x))), data.frame(x), FUN=sum))` is appropriate for. Could you give me a hint on this?

Comment: I have added some hints

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot!!